# print html table without a prompt a preview window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm going to print a html table using a button and onclick function. 
when i'm trying to do this it is prompt me a window always and from there i have to press again a button call print. then only the document is going to printer.

so what i want is to print that table form one button click and without any prompt for print preview, is it possible to do it? and how?

i'm using this code to print the table.

```
function printlayout() {
     var data = '<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">';           
       var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById('printlayout');
var WindowObject = window.open('', "TrackHistoryData", 
                              "width=740,height=325,top=200,left=250,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=no");           
 WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML);
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();
 }
```

i know there is thousands of questions here similar to this but nothing helped me to solve my problem.. I mostly focusing the Google chrome browser to run my application.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this is not possible, that feature is under control of the browser and you cannot manipulate that.